# Javascript: Insert an element to an array right after the referenced element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have an array, and an array of objects, each of which contain a reference to an element in the first array and a value to be inserted to the original array.

What will be the code to insert the desired value of the object in the second array, right after the referenced element in the first array?

For example, this is what I am trying to do:

```
const fruits = ["apple","melon", "banana", "kiwi"]
const colors = [{ref: "apple", color: "red"}, {ref: "banana", color:"yellow"}]

const result = ["apple", "red", "melon", "banana", "yellow", "kiwi"];
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: simplest thing would be to make `colors` an object: `= {"apple":"red", "banana":"yellow"}`, and then check for existence of fruit, and insert it's value if found.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Arrays should normally contain homogeneous data, you shouldn't mix different types of data in an array. And there's no way to tell which elements will be fruits versus colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (`colorMap`) which is keyed by `ref` from your `colors` array. The Map would would end up having the following structure:

```
{
  "apple" => ["apple", "red"]
  "banana" => ["banana", "yellow"]
}
```

As you can see, each key in the map is the fruit with it's associated array as its value. Once you have the `colorMap`, you can use the [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method on your `fruits` array which will allow you to transform each element. If a fruit exists in the `colorMap`, you can map the fruit to the elements stored in the fruits key, if it doesn't exist, you can take a default value of the fruit itself using `|| fruit`.

See example below:

```js
const fruits = ["apple","melon", "banana", "kiwi"]
const colors = [{ref: "apple", color: "red"}, {ref: "banana", color:"yellow"}];

const colorMap = new Map(colors.map(({ref, color}) => [ref, [ref, color]]));
const res = fruits.flatMap(fruit => colorMap.get(fruit) || fruit);
console.log(res);
```

If you [can't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility) `.flatMap()`, then you can consider using a regular [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then flattening the array using [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const fruits = ["apple","melon", "banana", "kiwi"]
const colors = [{ref: "apple", color: "red"}, {ref: "banana", color:"yellow"}];

const colorMap = new Map(colors.map(({ref, color}) => [ref, [ref, color]]));
const res = [].concat(...fruits.map(fruit => colorMap.get(fruit) || fruit));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is using the forEach loop .

```js
const fruits = ["apple","melon", "banana", "kiwi"]
const colors = [{ref: "apple", color: "red"}, {ref: "banana", color:"yellow"}]

var result= [];
fruits.forEach(fruit => {

result.push(fruit);
colors.forEach(color => {

    if(fruit === color.ref){result.push(color.color)}
});

});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the position of `ref` and `color` does not change

```
const insert = (fruits, colors) => {
    const newFruits = result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fruits));
    const newColors = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(colors));
    newColors.forEach(element => {
        let elem = Object.values(element);
        newFruits.map((element, index) => {
            if (element === elem[0]) {
                result.splice(index+1, 0, elem[1])
            }
        })
    });
    return result;
}
```